# How to add a FormField to section without a position using iText?

Tags: java, itext

In want to add interactive formfields like checkboxes to a newly created multiple page PDF, in the [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=154) from iText the code looks like this:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(180, 806  * 40, 200, 788  * 40);
RadioCheckField checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, "box1", "Yes");
PdfFormField field = checkbox.getCheckField();
writer.addAnnotation(field);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("checkbox1", normal), 210, 790 * 40, 0);
```

But this uses absolute positions and I don't know the position because the content before the field has optional images and text parts, where I don't know how many lines they take. 
I am also using Chapters and Sections, so I would like to use something like this:

```
Section section = chap.addSection(new Paragraph("sectionTitel",header2));
section.add(new Paragraph("line before field"));
//add FormField
section.add(field);
section.add(new Paragraph("line after field"));
```

Have you an idea how to do something like this or how to get the position from the line before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example for displaying checkboxes or radiobuttons without specifying positions. You need to use PdfPTable. http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CreateRadioInTable . There is one issue for displaying radiobuttons on multiple pages which I have posted here [Issue with iText RadioCheckField when displayed on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895930/issue-with-itext-radiocheckfield-when-displayed-on-multiple-pages) and still waiting for answers

Comment: For checkboxes the cellLayout method hast to look like in this example <http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CreateFormInTable>
The problem with multiple pages doesn't occur with the checkboxes, however the reason for this probably is that they have no radiogroup.